# How to append a text or number range to a div using javascript?

Tags: javascript, append

I inherited a JS file that goes like this:

```
    var id1 = document.getElementById("id1");
    var id2 = document.getElementById("id2");
    var id3 = document.getElementById("id3");
    var id4 = document.getElementById("id4"); //etc etc.
```

I was wondering if there is an easier way using plain Javascript to append a number to an id that has the same name, rather than listing each one out line by line.

Please advise.

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you want to append?

Comment: just a number identifier since the DOM has 50 elements with the same element ID - for example "bill", with a number identifier as indicated in the above example "bill1", "bill2",.. Thought maybe there is a way to reduce the writing of this long list :-) Thanks

Comment: try using a [`for` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var nodes = [];
var find = 6;

for (var i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
  nodes.push(document.getElementById('id' + i));
}

console.log(nodes);
```

```html
<div id="id1"></div>
<div id="id2"></div>
<div id="id3"></div>
<div id="id4"></div>
<div id="id5"></div>
<div id="id6"></div>
```

---

## A more robust solution:

Use `querySelectorAll` to select elements that have id's that begin with `id`, then filter out the results that do not match `id` followed by a number.

```js
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="id"]');
nodes = [].slice.call(nodes).filter(function(node) {
  return /id\d+/.test(node.id);
});

console.log(nodes);
```

```html
<div id="id1"></div>
<div id="id2"></div>
<div id="id3"></div>
<div id="id4"></div>
<div id="id5"></div>
<div id="id6"></div>
<!-- This node should not be included -->
<div id="idea"></div>
```